# What is the correct way to use async/await in a recursive method?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, recursion, async-await

What is the correct way to use async/await in a recursive method? Here is my method:

```
public string ProcessStream(string streamPosition)
{
    var stream = GetStream(streamPosition);

    if (stream.Items.count == 0)
        return stream.NextPosition;

    foreach(var item in stream.Items) {
        ProcessItem(item);
    }

    return ProcessStream(stream.NextPosition)
}
```

And here is the method with async/await:

```
public async Task<string> ProcessStream(stringstreamPosition)
{
        var stream = GetStream(streamPosition);

        if (stream.Items.count == 0)
            return stream.NextPosition;

        foreach(var item in stream.Items) {
            await ProcessItem(item); //ProcessItem() is now an async method
        }

        return await ProcessStream(stream.NextPosition);
 }
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors with what you tried?

Comment: @StephenCleary Nope, seems to be working fine. I was just wondering if there is any potential danger.

Comment: @zerkms How is my code synchronous?  With the await keyword, the method should return right away to the caller right? I only started learning async/await today, so there's likely a lot of gaps in my understanding.

Comment: @Prabhu: yep, it's my mistake

Comment: Looks pretty correct to me. Not sure what you're expecting here.

Comment: You're missing some line terminators (`;`), and using your `stream.NextPosition` as if it was a `string` when you return, but `int` when you pass it on to `ProcessStream`. Now that we got that out of the way, this method is trivial to implement as a simple loop, avoiding recursion altogether - and that's a good idea, because in synchronous scenarios (including cases where your recursive `Task`s complete synchronously) recursion can lead to `StackOverflowException`s. *Probably* won't happen in your particular case, but why you'd even take that risk when you can use a simple loop, is beyond me.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy thanks for the pointers. I've corrected the code. Would you mind giving me a code snippet for the non-recursive way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While I have to say upfront that the intention of the method is not entirely clear to me, reimplementing it with a simple loop is quite trivial:

```
public async Task<string> ProcessStream(string streamPosition)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var stream = GetStream(streamPosition);

        if (stream.Items.Count == 0)
            return stream.NextPosition;

        foreach (var item in stream.Items)
        {
            await ProcessItem(item); //ProcessItem() is now an async method
        }

        streamPosition = stream.NextPosition;
    }
}
```

Recursion is not stack-friendly and if you have the option of using a loop, it's something definitely worth looking into in simple synchronous scenarios (where poorly controlled recursion eventually leads to `StackOverflowException`s), as well as asynchronous scenarios, where, I'll be honest, I don't even know what would happen if you push things too far (my VS Test Explorer crashes whenever I try to reproduce known stack overflow scenarios with `async` methods).

Answers such as [Recursion and the await / async Keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808166/recursion-and-the-await-async-keywords) suggest that `StackOverflowException` is less of a problem with `async` due to the way the `async/await` state machine works, but this is not something I have explored much as I tend to avoid recursion whenever possible.

Comment: @Krill awesome thanks. Another issue is that the foreach is going to process one after the other because it is awaiting ProcessItem. Is there anyway to speeden it up so that it is' not waiting for ProcessItem.  I sort of need to just fire and forget, but if I take out the await, the compiler gives me a warning that not using the await in an async method is not a good idea.

Comment: @Prabhu, that is highly scenario-specific and depends on multiple factors, i.e. how thread-safe your code is, and how many items you expect `stream.Items` to contain. Thread-safety is paramount, and you need to ensure that multiple `ProcessItems` can run in parallel. Beyond that - if the number of items is not significant but each takes long time to process, I'd be replacing the `foreach` with `await Task.WhenAll(stream.Items.Select(ProcessItem));`. It the number of items is large and processing quick, I'd be reverting back to synchronous processing and using `Parallel.ForEach` instead.

Comment: in my case the number of items is very large. Curious to know why parallel.ForEach (which is what I have for now) will perform better in this case.

Comment: @Prabhu, that's because `Task`s are quite "heavy" and you really don't want one per item when dealing with *large* collections. `Parallel.ForEach` uses smart collection partitioning to achieve parallelisation without too much overhead (not counting cases where you're dealing with *really* small delegate bodies), and provides a number of optional tweaks and optimisations (i.e. local state), which you should look into in order to squeeze every last bit of performance out of it.

Comment: Thank you. Could I do a fire and forget on ProcessItem(item) somehow?

Comment: @Prabhu, you can, but why would you? Now you'll have all these parallel tasks running around flooding your thread pool and what not, throwing unobserved exceptions all over the place. Not good. Do you want to do this because you're trying to speed up the loop, or is it because `GetStream` can take a while and you ultimately want the producer (`GetStream`) and consumer (`foreach -> ProcessItem`) running in parallel?

Comment: Yeah I want to speed up my loop. While the for loop is running its work in parallel, the while loop is going to wait each iteration until the for loop is done doing all the ProcessItem()s, hence my concern.

Comment: I don't have the code for your producer OR your consumer, so this is a wild stab in the dark, but if the whole synchronous producer-consumer situation is bothering you and you think that the two can be parallelised nicely, then look into TPL Dataflow, or a simple pipeline (very basic example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467373/c-sharp-parallel-library-xmlreader-xmlwriter/24468103#24468103 , fully explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963548.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

When I add code to make your example more concrete, I find two possible ways for the recursion to turn out badly. Both of them assume that your data is pretty big and require specific conditions to trigger.

1. If `ProcessItem(string)` returns a `Task` that completes before it is `await`ed on (or, I assume, it completes before the `await` finishes spinning), the continuation will execute synchronously. In my code below, I have simulated this by having `ProcessItem(string)` return `Task.CompletedTask`. When I do this, the program *very* quickly terminates with a `StackOverflowException`. This is because .net’s TPL “[Releases](http://blog.izs.me/post/59142742143/designing-apis-for-asynchrony) [Zalgo](http://blog.ometer.com/2011/07/24/callbacks-synchronous-and-asynchronous/)” by [opportunistically executing continuations synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22579206/429091) without regard to how much space is available in the current stack. That means that it will *exacerbate* the potential stack space issue that you already have by using a recursive algorithm. To see this, comment out `await Task.Yield();` in my code sample below.
2. If you use some technique to prevent TPL from continuing synchronously (below I use `Task.Yield()`), eventually the program will run out of memory and die with an `OutOfMemoryException`. If I understand correctly, this wouldn’t happen if `return await` were able to emulate the tail-call optimization. I imagine that what is happening here is each call generates something like a book-keeping `Task<string>` and keeps generating them even though they could be coalesced. To reproduce this error with the sample below, ensure you’re running the program as 32-bit, disable the `Console.WriteLine()` call (because consoles are really slow), and ensure the `await Task.Yield()` is uncommented.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// Be sure to run this 32-bit to avoid making your system unstable.
class StreamProcessor
{
    Stream GetStream(string streamPosition)
    {
        var parsedStreamPosition = Convert.ToInt32(streamPosition);
        return new Stream(
            // Terminate after we reach 0.
            parsedStreamPosition > 0 ? new[] { streamPosition, } : new string[] { },
            Convert.ToString(parsedStreamPosition - 1));
    }

    Task ProcessItem(string item)
    {
        // Comment out this next line to make things go faster.
        Console.WriteLine(item);
        // Simulate the Task represented by ProcessItem finishing in
        // time to make the await continue synchronously.
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task<string> ProcessStream(string streamPosition)
    {
        var stream = GetStream(streamPosition);

        if (stream.Items.Count == 0)
            return stream.NextPosition;

        foreach (var item in stream.Items)
        {
            await ProcessItem(item); //ProcessItem() is now an async method
        }

        // Without this yield (which prevents inline synchronous
        // continuations which quickly eat up the stack),
        // you get a StackOverflowException fairly quickly.
        // With it, you get an OutOfMemoryException eventually—I bet
        // that “return await” isn’t able to tail-call properly at the Task
        // level or that TPL is incapable of collapsing a chain of Tasks
        // which are all set to resolve to the value that other tasks
        // resolve to?
        await Task.Yield();

        return await ProcessStream(stream.NextPosition);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static int Main(string[] args) => new Program().Run(args).Result;
    async Task<int> Run(string[] args)
    {
        await new StreamProcessor().ProcessStream(
            Convert.ToString(int.MaxValue));
        return 0;
    }
}

class Stream
{
    public IList<string> Items { get; }
    public string NextPosition { get; }
    public Stream(
        IList<string> items,
        string nextPosition)
    {
        Items = items;
        NextPosition = nextPosition;
    }
}
```

So, I guess my two recommendations are:

1. Use `Task.Yield()` if you aren’t certain that the stack growth of recursion will be interrupted by something else.
2. [As suggested already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25009734/429091), avoid recursion if it doesn’t even make sense for your problem in the first place. And even if it makes a clean algorithm, avoid it if your problem size is unbounded.