# Converting a Parallel.ForEach loop into parallel tasks using lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asynchronous, async-await

Need help converting this to a lamdba expression where I can use Task.WhenAll:

```
public void DoWork(string id)
{            
       var items = GetItems(id);  //takes time

       if (items == null)
       {
            return;
       }

       Parallel.ForEach(items, item =>
       {
            DoSomething(item); //takes time
            DoWork(item.subItemId);                    
       });           
}
```

I would like to change the Parallel For loop into tasks using a lambda expressions as suggested in Martin's answer in this thread:
[How to call an async method from within a loop without awaiting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009317/how-to-call-an-async-method-from-within-a-loop-without-awaiting/25009961#25009961)

Not sure how to specify the multiple line after item =>. This doesn't seem to work:

```
public void DoWork(string id)
{            
       var items = GetItems(id);  //takes time

       if (items == null)
       {
           return;
       } 

       var tasks = items.Select(item => 
       {
           DoSomething(item)
           DoWork(item.subItemId)
       });      

       await Task.WhenAll(tasks);         
}
```

UPDATE:

Thank you all for your answers. If I have an if condition, would I be wasting tasks? Is there a better to code this?  Do I need to be using Where instead?

```
var tasks = items.Select(async item => 
{ 
    if (item.HasWork)
    {
       await DoSomethingAsync(item);
       await DoWorkAsync(item.subItemId);
    }
});      

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Note that you should be somewhat wary of recursive `async` methods.  It's probably worth transforming this method into being iterative, rather than recursive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's easiest to use an `async` lambda:

```
public async Task DoWorkAsync(string id)
{            
  var items = GetItems(id);  //takes time

  if (items == null)
    return;

  var tasks = items.Select(async item => 
  { 
    await DoSomethingAsync(item);
    await DoWorkAsync(item.subItemId);
  });      

  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);         
}
```

[Martin's original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009317/how-to-call-an-async-method-from-within-a-loop-without-awaiting/25009961#25009961) assumes you'd write your own `async` method instead of an `async` lambda, which may make the code clearer:

```
public async Task DoWorkAsync(string id)
{            
  var items = GetItems(id);  //takes time

  if (items == null)
    return;

  var tasks = items.Select(item => ProcessAsync(item));

  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);         
}

private async Task ProcessAsync(T item)
{
  await DoSomethingAsync(item);
  await DoWorkAsync(item.subItemId);
}
```

Comment: thanks.  Question is, do I need to make DoSomething and DoWork as Async?  Could I keep them as regular sync methods and follow Selman22's or Castro's answer, and still get the full benefit of parallel processing?

Comment: @Prabhu: You stated in a comment that you get the "compiler warning saying I am not using the await keyword for DoSomething and DoWork". So I infer they're already asynchronous; I just renamed them to [follow the naming convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx).

Comment: Sure. But DoSomething and DoWork are my methods, so I am able to make then non-async if it will make things simpler. Is there a benefit of keeping them async?

Comment: They should be asynchronous if they have asynchronous work to do (usually I/O). They should be synchronous if they have synchronous work to do (usually CPU computation). Let the *operation* determine how the *method* looks; don't force the method to be a certain way, imposing a mismatching signature onto the operation.

Comment: do you see a potential problem with DoWorkAsync being recursive?

Comment: @Prabhu: I generally avoid recursive code in C#; C# is not a functional language, so there is a definite stack limit that you can run into (the rules for when tail-recursion optimization applies are horribly complex and not stable from version to version). `async` lets you escape some of that, but only if it truly acts asynchronously; e.g., if an awaited task is already complete, the method will act *synchronously*, and then you can really run into stack problems with recursive async. It's best to avoid recursion in C#.

Comment: Thanks.  I updated my question, had another doubt..if I have an if condition wrapping DoSomething and DoWork, then would I be creating empty tasks for some items (when the if is false)?  Is there a better way to deal with the if condition?

Comment: A `Where` would be a bit more efficient, but not a groundbreaking performance improvement.