# multiple asynchronous calls inside an iterative loop

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, c#-5.0

I am trying to follow something give in the below url [Async and Await with For Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069487/async-and-await-with-for-loop/26074520#26074520)

However one thing which i need is to kill all the task if any one of them fails.
How can this be done in the LoadAsync method given.

Answer (score 0):

That answer would not work at all because `Parallel` is not async aware. The Parallel lambda will simply return immediately with a task being produced. That task is *not* awaited on. It's thrown away. Therefore the loop will exit immediately after starting *all* work and not wait for any work to finish.

You can achieve cancellation by first creating a `CancellationTokenSource` and passing its `Token` property around to all code that you want to cancel. The code must itself pass that token around or periodically check the token.

When you call the `Cancel()` method all activity will be signaled to cancel and come to an end.

You can implement the loop using https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/05/implementing-a-simple-foreachasync-part-2/:

```
public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int dop, Func<T, Task> body) 
{ 
    return Task.WhenAll( 
        from partition in Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(dop) 
        select Task.Run(async delegate { 
            using (partition) 
                while (partition.MoveNext()) 
                    await body(partition.Current); 
        })); 
}
```